# Gatsby Remark sidecar files for galleries, video, credits, etc.?

Tags: javascript, gatsby

I am looking for a little nudge in the right direction for solving some graphql/filesystem/frontmatter/parsing challenges as a newcomer to gatsby...

I have a large collection of nested folders of markdown files for project posts I've generated from a historical django site. I'm using the `collection` query to query varying page types (blog, project, etc)

The project structure looks something like this and there are about 300 work/project folders in various years:

```
/content/
    work/
        2000/
            brandname-title/
                index.md
                credits.md
                images.md
                videos.md
                images/
                    index.md
                    gallery1.md
                    gallery1/
                        image1.jpg
                        image2.jpg
                    gallery2.md
                    gallery2/
                        image1.jpg
                        image2.jpg
                videos/
                    index.md
                    video1.md
                    video1/
                        video1.mp4
                        video1.ogv
                    video2.md
                    video2/
                        video2.mp4
                        video2.mov
```

The blog structure is similar with less media and it's mutable if need be.

I want the `index.md` file for each project to be it's corresponding page with it's stub/sidecar files not considered as pages but useable as content within the main page. The same goes for subfolders. The `index.md` file represents the main content and the other stub/sidecar markdown files are used to store the data.

I'm hoping to have the following routes resolve:

```
2000/                           (all projects from 2000)
2000/brandname-title/           (the index.md file with images, videos, credits)
2000/brandname-title/images/    (gallery1 and gallery2)
2000/brandname-title/videos/    (video1 and video2)
```

Give me a nudge... linkslap...

Answer (score 1):

Never tried that, but if you just need a nudge... I think you'll want to split what [gatsby-transformer-remark](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-transformer-remark/) does (compile Markdown files into html and give you access to it) and what the [Gatbsy Node API](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/node-apis/) does (create page routes).

So you would start like the [documentation says](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/adding-markdown-pages/), then:

1. in `gatsby-config.js` you would grab *all* markdown files, but
2. in `gatsby-node.js` create pages just from *some* of them, then
3. in your page template use GraphQL to get the content of the "partials".